# Meteor errors while adding packages

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm trying to add bootstrap3: glyphicons in the meteor through the terminal and is giving this error. Any idea on how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: It is because of package incompatibly. Trying to update meteor using `meteor update` should fix it. You can also try to force the package version of your package in `.meteor/version` file.

Comment: what version is ```less``` tagged to in your ./meteor/packages file?

Comment: @SudheerJami i tried to use the 'meteor update' and it still gives the same error

Comment: @blueren i'm using the less@2.7.9

Comment: Why exactly do you need ```bootstrap3:glyphicons```? If you install ```twbs:bootstrap``` I believe it will take care of glyphicons as well. Give that a try. Also, if you notice, [bootstrap3:glyphicons](https://atmospherejs.com/bootstrap3/glyphicons) has been flagged as not working.

Comment: @blueren Thank you so much, `twbs:bootstrap` fixed my problem.

Comment: after i've add the `twbs:bootstrap` all the input tags are thin, 
and even if I set the thickness in a css class, the thickness remains the same. How can i fix this ?

Comment: @gleysersantos - good to know. If you're happy with the outcome, then choose an answer below so that this is no longer an open question.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use package **twbs:bootstrap**

Comment: after i've add the `twbs:bootstrap` all the input tags are thin, 
and even if I set the thickness in a css class, the thickness remains the same. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you need `bootstrap3:glyphicons`? If you install `twbs:bootstrap` I believe it will take care of glyphicons as well. Give that a try. Also, if you notice, bootstrap3:glyphicons has been flagged as not working.